# omp parallel for output order

Tags: c, loops, io, parallel-processing, openmp

I made this simple program to test the openmp libraries:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  char buffer[10];
  FILE *fp1;
  sprintf(buffer, "out.txt");
  fp1=fopen(buffer, "a"); 
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    fprintf(fp1, "%d ", i);
}
```

And i obtain the following results: 8 
9 
14 
15 
0 
1 
6 
7 
4 
5 
2 
3 
12 
13 
10 
11

So I tried a simpler program to just put the numbers on the terminal:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    printf("%d ", i);
}
```

When i Run it here's my output:
12
13 
4 
5 
0 
1 
6 
7 
2 
3 
14 
15 
10 
11 
8 
9

I'd like to understand why the variable i isn't taken in order by my cores, I expected something like: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16.

Edit: Yes I have 8 cores. Thanks all for the answers, now it's clear.

Comment: "I ran parallel code and expected sequential behaviour" - why do you expect that output? What are you expecting the "parallel" thing to change? (I guess you have 8 cores? See how each core does sequential listing (12,13), (2,3)) but the whole lot runs all at once, and it's a toss-up which finishes first)

Comment: Yep this makes sense. But I thought for some reason that the first cores to get the values were the first to print the output. My bad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **parallel execution**.

Understanding how a parallel program handles output is one of the first concepts you should grasp, before moving on, since it *will* help you later when you actually develop something cool.

---

That means that every thread starts and whoever finishes first or/and gets first the output resources (the bus for the stdout buffer in that case), prints first.

Notice the output:

> 8 9 14 15 0 1 6 7 4 5 2 3 12 13 10 11

You can identify that  the numbers are printed in pairs (4,5 for example).

Do you have 8 cores? If so, then you could determine the chunks, 16 numbers diving by 8 cores, thus 2 numbers per core, which would explain why the output is printed in pairs.

Notice that by pairs I mean that you can see the sequential behavior in that chunk of numbers. Every thread will print its numbers in order.

---

Same applies for your simpler program.

---

Let me put it in other words:

Assuming you have 8 cores, you can imagine that your computer will actually execute 8 programs. Every program will print 16/8 = 2 numbers. Every program's core would actually look like this:

```
int offset = omp knows what to put here
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = offset; i < offset + 2; i++)
  printf("%d ", i);
```

So for the 2nd (sub)program `offset` will be equal to 2.

Now imagine you have 8 terminals open and you have the above (sub)program compiled and ready to run by the executable name subProgram.

Let's assume you are as fast as a Jolteon and accomplish to start executing `./subProgram` in every single terminal, such that the starting time that the terminal/user submitted the program for execution to the OS is the same.

Which subprogram will print first?

You cannot tell! Since you have 8 subprograms that want to use one resource (the screen). So, whoever arrives first at the finish line, the screen, will print first.

That's an analogy to what happens in parallel execution.

---

Notice that in real-world programs, when the data are bigger (of course they are! Otherwise why bother with [parallel-proccesing](/questions/tagged/parallel-proccesing)?), even the order of the output of every program is not guaranteed.

That means that the 1st (sub)program may execute the first iteration, but by the time it will execute the second iteration, another (sub)program may have already executed its first execution and claim the resource (screen).

Comment: Can I force every sub program to specific cores?

Comment: I would swear I had seen a question in SO mentioning the same thing. You should not do that though, parallel computing doesn't work that way.. @FrancescoDiLauro

Comment: By the way, here in Stack Overflow we accept an answer when we find it helpful to our question @FrancescoDiLauro! :) As for the edit, I would kindly ask you to post a new question, asking the entirely new thing you are asking! :)

Comment: Hey :-) I'm kinda newbye here. How do I accept answers?

Comment: I was like you 3 years ago, I know the feel! Nice question BTW, you deserved my upvote @FrancescoDiLauro!